# Responding to AJAX Rails request with .js.erb and Rails instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

I am struggling w/ JS AJAX requests in Rails. There is an official guide [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example), but I am having slight difficulties matching it with ES6 JS. I am having troubles passing things back to my frontend after making my requests.

I have a JS window.onload call made, because I am trying to find the user’s screen size (among other things) and pass it back to Rails:

```
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = "/users";
    xhttp.open("POST", url);
    // Some other things added to it...
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 201) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
       }
    };
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({user_info: userInfo}));
```

It is posting to /users some information about the session. This is going through fine. Note the `console.log` that keeps track of the response, we will get to this later.

In my Rails controller:

```
def create
  user_info = params[:user_info].permit!
  user_info = user_info.to_s
  @fingerprint_user =  User.find_or_create_by(fingerprint: user_info)
  respond_to do |format|
    # NOTE: I have tried a few things here
    # format.html { redirect_to @fingerprint_user, notice: "Successfully identified user by fingerprint." }
    # format.js
    format.json { render json: @fingerprint_user, status: :created, head: :ok }
  end
end
```

**The JSON sender is working correctly**. The console.log in the JS above correctly console.logs the received JSON. The request responds with **201**, and the @fingerprint_user instance variable in JSON form.

**My problem is with returning ERB JS with the instance variable**. As shown in the guide, I have tried adding `format.js`. Then, the request returns a **200**, and the contents of my `views/users/create.js.erb` file:

```
console.log("hello");
```

However, it is not actually **logging to console.**

Lastly, I tried with **all format fields** (js, html, and json). Here is my `show.html.erb`:

```
<p>Got user: <%= @fingerprint_user.to_s %> </p>
```

Here is a better `views/users/create.js.erb` file, where `fingerprint` is a div in my `index.html.erb`:

```
console.log("hello");
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @fingerprint_user) %>").appendTo("#fingerprint");
```

Once again, the response is **200**, and the appropriate html, but this is not rendered on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing requests for AJAX requests for JavaScript is different then requesting JSON. Instead of requesting some data and parsing it you actually load the data and then eval it into the current page context through various tricks like appending script tags into the document. This is the actual [Rails UJS implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5b28a0e972da31da570ed24be505ef7958ab4b5e/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/ajax.coffee#L63):

```
processResponse = (response, type) ->
  if typeof response is 'string' and typeof type is 'string'
    if type.match(/\bjson\b/)
      try response = JSON.parse(response)
    else if type.match(/\b(?:java|ecma)script\b/)
      script = document.createElement('script')
      script.setAttribute('nonce', cspNonce())
      script.text = response
      document.head.appendChild(script).parentNode.removeChild(script)
    else if type.match(/\b(xml|html|svg)\b/)
      parser = new DOMParser()
      type = type.replace(/;.+/, '') # remove something like ';charset=utf-8'
      try response = parser.parseFromString(response, type)
  response
```

This is basically how we used to do AJAX calls cross domain ten years ago with [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to get around the limitations of the browsers of the day.

You can emulate the same thing in a "raw ajax request" with:

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "/users";
xhttp.open("POST", url);
// Some other things added to it...
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 201) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = data;
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
  }
};
```

But quite frankly `js.erb` is a horrible idea. It makes an absolute mess out of the server and client side responibilities and makes your code very difficult to follow and reason about and it moves JS out of the assets/webpack pipeline and into a smattering of proceedural junk script views. The only possible reason to use it is how lazy you can be with Rails UJS and still add some ajax to your application.

If you're writing an ajax handler anyways just return a chunk of html (in a json object or as html) and append it to the DOM instead.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! It makes sense that the issue was *how I handled the response with JS*. With your suggestion, I also dropped the `js.erb`. 

In my `onreadystatechange`: `document.querySelector('#fingerprint').innerHTML = this.response;`. In my controller, I just used format.html and json, and changed the html to `render` instead of redirect. I changed my html filename to `_user.html.erb`.

Comment: w.r.t. "frankly `js.erb` is a horrible idea" - I think this makes sense for my use case. I have external JS, and there is no need to have JS in two places. The impression that I get is that `js.erb` should be used only when you 1) don't have other JS 2) need it only for a specific page, so it seems a bit narrow. Thanks again!